# Drawing offscreen WebView to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, webview

I am trying to capture a image of a webview drawn off screen to the user in android and i always end up with a black image. It is the correct size and everything just not the

Here is the code I am using:

```
String theURL = "file:///android_asset/www/pages/page2.html";
        WebView webview = new WebView(ctx);
        webview.loadUrl(theURL);
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
        webview.draw(c);
        OutputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/page.jpg");
            bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
            if (stream != null) stream.close();              
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e.toString());
        } finally {
            bm.recycle();
        }
```

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The `webview.loadUrl(theURL);` starts the loading of the page, that can take a while. Wait before drawing your webview until after the page is loaded. You can use a `setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client)` to set up an object to receive notice when the page has finished loading.