# WebViews inside ListView with MathJax

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview, mathjax

I have a application which must render **MathJax equations** and therefore I must use **WebView** layout because of lot of **JavaScript code** on MathJax side and many **images** that are dynamically displayed from MathJax **CDN service** (all handled by MathJax JS library).

It's working fine with single WebView layout and everything renders just fine - but the problem appears when I need to display the **search results** from my web API and every search result includes some MathJax code - you can imagine it as a Google Search results but with MathJax code/equations inside.

The first thing that crossed my mind is ListView with a WebView inside each row - but it's **very insufficient** and I'm putting scrollable webView inside scrollable listView, not a good idea. Also the webView renders each time I scroll a little bit, maybe I could use some cache to cache rendered WebView's but I'm not sure...

Are there any suggested alternatives? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render the webview into a bitmap, and keep these bitmaps cached.
You can do it while it is visible, like here:
[Rendering Android webview to bitmap, html5 javascript , callback issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009265/rendering-android-webview-to-bitmap-html5-javascript-callback-issue)
or do it in the background, like here: [Drawing offscreen WebView to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467214/drawing-offscreen-webview-to-bitmap)